# How to add animation to input placeholder

Tags: html, css

I'm making a search placeholder with which i want animation to be done. I tried , but it's not working.

My css codes are :

```
@-webkit-keyframes search_types {
from { width:0px;}
to {width:100px;}
}
.input_search_box::-webkit-input-placeholder{
   -webkit-animation: search_types 10s infinite linear;
}
```

I have tried many ways, transition works but i want to use animation for some other purpose , is there anyway way to do it. 
 I want to do a type animation [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/y8kNx) in the placeholder

Comment: You can't as far as I know. `placeholder` isn't an element...it's an attribute.

Comment: but we can add other css like `color` , `font-family`

Comment: how do you imagine the final result? maybe you can achieve it in other way

Comment: Hmmm...perhaps it's inline...have you tried setting it to `inline-block`?

Comment: just did, not working.

Comment: Maybe we can use `span` tag and animate it...

Comment: Hmmm...this is a little out of date but it looks like width isn't a supported property for it - http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/02/styling-the-html5-placeholder/

Comment: have a look at [This](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/ah82vLt6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting post, i find a solution to put an :before content to the placeholder and make the animation on.
The content are a blank box on absolute position at the right and we animate the width. So we can retrieve the behavior that you wanted I guess :

```
@-webkit-keyframes search_types {
    from {width: 100%;}
    to {width:0px;}
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    position: relative;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-animation: search_types 10s infinite linear;
}
```

Curiously we cant apply :before content ton input element but placeholder!
Dont forget to apply the prefix for all support browser:

- ::-webkit-input-placeholder
- :-moz-placeholder
- ::-moz-placeholder
- :-ms-input-placeholder

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/ky5g2n8r/